# Remove padding in table

Tags: css, element-ui

I am using Element UI table for to tabulate my data. My problem is I cant remove the padding inside the cell. This is before I make any changes.
[image: before]

I want to remove all the spaces around the green box. I add this code to remove the padding.

```
<el-table :data="tableData" size="mini" :cell-style="{ padding: 0 }">
```

This is after added the code.

[image: after]

Only top and bottom padding is removed but the left and right padding remains. I think the padding is from `cell class` but I'm not sure how to remove it.

[image: cell class]

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
.el-table .cell {
  padding: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make the div padding 0 the container

```
.el-table {
   padding: 0px
}
```

Comment: if you provide the html maybe i or the community can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Basic Table from the element framework website -- to lose all the padding it would be..

```
.el-table td {padding:0;}
```

If you can provide your html in a snippet, you would get specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
.el-table td, .el-table th.is-leaf {border-bottom: 1px solid #ebeef5;padding: 0px;}
```

This can be achieved by making the `padding` as `0px`.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it on other answer, credits [Fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7147172/fab):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60491030/7270723

Basicly, you should create your class into your style without the scope attribute:

```
<style>
.selected-cell {
  padding:0 !important;
}     
</style>

<style scoped>

/* other styles here*/

</style>
```

Then, into the methods create it:

```
cellStyle() {
  return "selected-cell"
},
```

finally, in your  use :cell-class-name="cellStyle" :

```
<el-table
    :data="tableData"
    :cell-class-name="cellStyle"  >
```